# Three Phase rectifier

Tags: motor, diodes, rectifier, three-phase, bridge-rectifier

I just bought a **electric bike BLDC motor** that i have to use as a DC generator, in order to charge a 12V battery.

I have many questions, all related to this project but seeing it from quite different perspectives:

1-  What kind of **voltage/power/current** does a 12V 130Ah battery for boat need to be charged ?

2-  What does **36V** represent in "250W36V" (*which is the only information I have on this motor*) ? The RMS value ? The max voltage for each one of the three inductors of the Wye-shaped three-phase ? The max voltage between two pf the three phases ?

3-  What does **250W** represent in "250W36V" ?

4-  How can I find the **current value** of each one of the three phases ? *(is it as simple as simply calculating 250/36 ? It really depends on the answers to the previous questions, I know)*

5-  Having this information, how exactly can I **choose the correct kind of diodes** I need ?

Please, please, even if you don't have all the information, can you leave the smallest clue you have in mind ? It might seem like very little to you, but could mean the world to me.

Have a great day!

Motor: https://xiongdamotor.en.alibaba.com/product/1178837248-218695257/YTW_01_24V_or_36V_permanent_magnet_brushless_dc_motor_for_electric_bicycle.html

Comment: You should provide more details on the motor if you want a good answer. You definitely need to provide more details on the battery if you expect any answers.

Comment: The goal is to charge a boat battery: 130Ah and 12V.

What kind of information do you need about the motor ? 
Here is a link: https://xiongdamotor.en.alibaba.com/product/1178837248-218695257/YTW_01_24V_or_36V_permanent_magnet_brushless_dc_motor_for_electric_bicycle.html

Comment: Why O why would you buy a motor if you don't understand what it does nor what it needs to do?  How could you possibly know that the motor you bought can do the job you want it to?

Comment: Well the hardest part was actually to find a motor that would provide the right power, and would match our expectations regarding the rotational speed and efficiency. Not mentionning the modelization of the rest of the project, to which the motor is an essential part, but also a very small part. We are specialized in physics more than electronics/electrotechnics, this is why I am now asking for help @OlinLathrop

Comment: See additions to my answer. Is this a university or technical institute project or ...? Where are you located?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, it is part of my intership in a french company

Comment: If size is not too much of a problem then using a **direct drive** "brushless DC motor" from a washing machine would probably be a better solution. Websearch for: fisher and Paykel smart drive or just smart drive BUT there are others. These may do what you want almost directly.

Comment: MANY examples [**here**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=smart+drive+alternator&num=50&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCuMbkja7VAhWBo5QKHVFcA6wQsAQIPA&biw=1680&bih=871) and here is a [nirco hydro alternator](http://www.currentgeneration.co.nz/INFORMATION/ABOUT+RENEWABLE+ENERGY/MICRO+HYDRO+WATER+TURBINE.html) installation making up to 1.2 kW and ...

Comment: ...  [many micro hydro conversions here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?num=50&q=smart+drive+alternator+micro+hydro&oq=smart+drive+alternator+micro+hydro&gs_l=psy-ab.3...15323.18379.0.18690.11.11.0.0.0.0.242.1948.2-9.9.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.7.1517...33i22i29i30k1j33i160k1j33i21k1.kgCaeInWIoo)

Comment: [More here using various alternators](https://www.google.co.nz/search?num=50&q=alternator+micro+hydro&oq=alternator+micro+hydro&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1l2j0i8i30k1l2.75479.75479.0.76038.1.1.0.0.0.0.281.281.2-1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.281.aoHoqT1gc5A)

Comment: [car alternator discussions here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?num=50&q=alternator+micro+hydro+car+alternator&oq=alternator+micro+hydro+car+alternator&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i21k1.44238.48660.0.48843.15.15.0.0.0.0.352.2109.2-8j1.9.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..6.9.2107...0i22i30k1j33i160k1.X2lqO4P-ryk) and [images with links here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=alternator+micro+hydro+car+alternator&num=50&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSrqH1jq7VAhVDjpQKHdeGCogQsAQIWg&biw=1680&bih=871)

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume a lead acid battery BUT you must be more specific (chemistry, cells, Ah, voltage. ...). Spec sheet link a very good idea. . Chemistry and even sub-type may affect answers.

> 1- What kind of voltage/power/current does a 12V battery need to be charged ?

See www.batteryuniversity.com BUT
the manufacturer will provide that information.
Batteries generally have a max charge current but for lead acid C/10 is usually safe - but faster may be viable.

> 2- What does 36V represent in "250W36V" ... The RMS value ? The max voltage for each one of the three inductors of the Wye-shaped three-phase ? The max voltage between two pf the three phases ?

The motor is designed to run on DC. At max power there is 36V DC on one phase to common at a time. When used as an alternator with rectification it will make ABOUT 36V loaded at rated speed and max load.

> 3- What does 250W represent in "250W36V" ?

250 Watts input power at 36V at full speed and load. As it's a 36V rated motor, VDC ~~+
I = Watts/V = 250/36 = 7A.

> 4- How can I find the current value of each one of the three phases ? (is it as simple as simply calculating 250/36 ? It really depends on the answers to the previous questions, I know)

Iphase conducting is &A RMS for 1/3 of time =7A
Total I = 7A.

5- Having all these informations, how exactly can I choose the correct kind of diodes I need ?

Diodes must handle 7A for 1/3 of each cycle. So eg may 5A diodes would suffice. A 10A part is "safer". Voltage rating min notionally 36V x sqrt(2) ~~= 50V BUT use at least 100V diodes.

---

**ADDED:**

If you tell us about the whole system we can help much more.

What is driving the generator? eg a petrol powered motor or wind turbine or ....?

What is the optimum speed in RPM of the driving source?

---

Sadly, it is possible that the motor you cite is not suitable.
It has an internal gearbox giving (claimed) 160 - 340 RPM at rated power.
Before gearing down the motor probably runs at at least 3000 RPM and MAY be **much**  faster again -  so the internal gearbox is probably at least ~= 10:1 and maybe much higher. This means that it MAY not do a good job of speeding up the 300 RPM to the required 3000 RPM and depending on design it may not be possible to use it this way at all.
SO please tell us as much as possible overall about your actual REQUIREMENT -
ie **not** HOW you think it can be solved but what you wish to actually do.

Note:
They say "**Because it is the built-in reduction gear motor ...**"

&

CE Type: Gear Motor
Construction: Permanent Magnet
Commutation: Brushless
**Speed(RPM): 160-340**
Output Power: ≥83%
Voltage(V): 24,36

[**User proposed motor**](https://xiongdamotor.en.alibaba.com/product/1178837248-218695257/YTW_01_24V_or_36V_permanent_magnet_brushless_dc_motor_for_electric_bicycle.html)

[image]

---

> Battery:  130Ah and 12V.

It is VERY likely that the solution proposed can be improved on, but:

At say 200 Watts output and 36V the generator would produce
I= P/V = 200/36 ~= 5.5A.
If this was used to directly charge a 130 Ah 12V battery it would take ~~
T = Ah/A > 1.1 = 130/5.5 x 1.1 = 26 hours.

If a "buck converter" was used to step the 36V, 200W down to closer to 12-14V required at an efficiency of say 85% then the available current would be
I ~~= Vin/Vout x Iin x efficincy =  36/13 x 5.5  x 0.85 ~= 13A
Charge time ~= 130/13 x 1.1 = 11 hours.

---

**Added 2:**

If size is not too much of a problem then using a direct drive "brushless DC motor" from a washing machine would probably be a better solution.
Web search for:
fisher and Paykel smart drive
or just
smart drive

Examples of smart drives in process of being utilised as alternators:

Diagrammatic view / As mounted in washing machine / Dual drive alternator / Stator / Mounted
Wind turbine mount / belt driven / Stator / Stator / Stator.

[image]
BUT there are others. These may do what you want almost directly.

This appears to be a French source of alternators / direct drive motors that may suit your need very well

[Big Jack Cycle, 80 Rue Montoise, 72000 Le Mans, France](http://bigjack-cycle.com/categories.asp?id_famille=5&id_categorie=32)

eg [image]

---

MANY examples [**here**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=smart+drive+alternator&num=50&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCuMbkja7VAhWBo5QKHVFcA6wQsAQIPA&biw=1680&bih=871)

And here is a [micro hydro alternator installation](http://www.currentgeneration.co.nz/INFORMATION/ABOUT+RENEWABLE+ENERGY/MICRO+HYDRO+WATER+TURBINE.html)  using a "smart drive motor as an alternator and making up to 1.2 kW

[Many micro hydro smart-drive conversions here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?num=50&q=smart+drive+alternator+micro+hydro&oq=smart+drive+alternator+micro+hydro&gs_l=psy-ab.3...15323.18379.0.18690.11.11.0.0.0.0.242.1948.2-9.9.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.7.1517...33i22i29i30k1j33i160k1j33i21k1.kgCaeInWIoo)

[More here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?num=50&q=alternator+micro+hydro&oq=alternator+micro+hydro&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1l2j0i8i30k1l2.75479.75479.0.76038.1.1.0.0.0.0.281.281.2-1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.281.aoHoqT1gc5A)  using various alternators

[Car alternator discussions here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?num=50&q=alternator+micro+hydro+car+alternator&oq=alternator+micro+hydro+car+alternator&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i21k1.44238.48660.0.48843.15.15.0.0.0.0.352.2109.2-8j1.9.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..6.9.2107...0i22i30k1j33i160k1.X2lqO4P-ryk)  and
[images with links here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=alternator+micro+hydro+car+alternator&num=50&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSrqH1jq7VAhVDjpQKHdeGCogQsAQIWg&biw=1680&bih=871)

---

[Excellent introduction to Smart Drive Alternator](http://www.thebackshed.com/windmill/articles/decoggingFP.asp)

From the above page:

http://www.nrel.gov/docs/fy02osti/30768.pdf
http://www.google.com/patents?id=s7cRAAAAEBAJ&dq=6784582
http://www.motordesignsolutions.com/pdf/ias03_metin.pdf
http://www.icrepq.com/icrepq-08/412-tudorache.pdf
http://journal.library.iisc.ernet.in/vol200604/paper5/355.pdf
http://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/829/1/wangjb11.pdf
http://www.epower-llc.com/pdf/LowNoisePMMotors.pdf
http://www.ieindia.org/pdf/87/ej0f1kk.pdf
http://www.ee.kth.se/php/modules/publications/reports/2003/IR-EE-EME_2003_029.pdf
http://people.clarkson.edu/~pillayp/c12.pdf
http://adt.curtin.edu.au/theses/available/adt-WCU20020610.111258/unrestricted/05Chapter4-4.7.1.pdf
http://opus.kobv.de/tuberlin/volltexte/2006/1338/pdf/widyan_mohammad.pdf

Comment: Thank you for this precious help ! I'll try getting more information on the battery and motor

Comment: The motor is connected to a boat propeller that only uses the movement of the boat _(pushed by the wind)_ to spin. 
We actually asked the manufacturer to get rid of the gearing, so that the speed = 900rpm (they also changed a few more things to get to 900rpm). 

We asked to get 900 because, according to our calculations, 959rpm would be the speed of alternator when connected to the turbine.

Comment: 639.8rpm _(speed of the turbine)_ x 1.5 _(coefficient of the gearing connecting the turbine to the motor)_ = 959rpm _(alternator's speed when the boat's turbine spin at 639.8rpm)_.

We carried out a study on mechanics of fluids to find the perfect shape for the propeller blades and the boat's speed. So 639.8rpm is a theoretical value, most definitely pretty accurate.

@Russel McMahon

Comment: The size (and weight) is actually quite important, as we intend to put it underwater and make it hold to a boat thanks to a system that will already be opposed to a great amount of water resistance. 

Here is the link to the battery's characteristics (BANNER ENERGY BULL 960 51: https://www.bannerbatterien.com/en/Products/Starter-Batteries/Energy-Bull/230-960-51

https://www.bannerbatterien.com/download/?file=409

Comment: @Sarah - more overall information needed but eg an alternator mounted on rear of a boat with a prop behind in the water is not overly critical for size or even weight. One of the direct drive motors I've referred to should work OK.